# Проблема( переписать массив структур в другой массив структур на assembler)

Tags: ассемблер

```
.386

 Tabl1   struc            // это шаблон структуры
 namex   db  8 dup(?)
 field2  dw  ?
 Tabl1   ENDS

 Data1   segment
 I1  db  0
 A1  Tabl1 6 dup(<>)
 Data1   ENDS

 Data2 segment use16
 A2 Tabl1 6 dup (<>)
 Data2 ends



 /* вот тут я пытаюсь переписать один массив структур в другой массив 
 структур начиная с 3 структуры*/

 code2 segment use16                    
 assume cs:code2, es:Data1, ds:Data2
 begin2:
 mov ax, Data1
 mov es, ax
 mov ax, Data2
 mov ds, ax
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69099/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: Уточните, что и куда нужно переписать.